# Android, how to securely store data from C++?

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I need to securely store a piece of data (a single string) on Android from a pure C++ implementation.

AFAIK the way to do this is using SharedPreferences and KeyStore. SharedPreferences takes care of simple storage and KeyStore of encrypting the data. This is done trivially in Java/Kotlin, but all the C++ answers seem to point to a JNI implementation (that just binds/calls Java classes and methods)

The problem is: I'm not looking for Java/JNI implementations, all my functionality is implemented in pure C++ using JSI (JavaScript ⇔ C++ communication) bindings, so I cannot use JNI code without a huge headache of macros and workarounds.

There are some hints, such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42127072/how-can-i-use-keystore-in-android-native-code), that it might be possible to use the low-level implementation of android. But I just cannot find any example on the web. I'm also not a C++ expert to go diving into AOSP source code.

Is this even possible? and if so, could anybody provide a simple example I could start with? Even just an example showing if the underlying frameworks are importable/includable in some custom C++ code would already be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is: no, after much fumbling around it is not worth it to try to achieve certain things from C++ on android. The solution I ended up was calling java methods (bridged used JNI) from my C++ code.